# Magento translations

Tags: magento-1.7, theme

Are magento translations managed through: app/locale/language_name, or app/design/frontend/default/My_themename/locale

Are there any priorities if they wxist in both places?

Can someone clearify this to me?

Thanks

Answer (score 10):

- Lowest priority: *app/locale/en_US/Module_File.csv*
- Medium: *[theme]/locale/en_US/translate.csv*
- Highest: `core_translate` table (via Inline Translation).

There are some other details, but this is a start.

Answer (score 1):

In your case app/design/frontend/default/My_themename/locale would overrule default default or even base default.

I like to use the inline translator. Go to System>Developer, put in your IP ins the Allowed IPs. Then under Translate Inline you will see Enable for Frontend. Select yes and save config.

Assuming whatever text you are trying to translate is written similar to this `<?php echo $this->__('some text') ?>` then it will allow you to translate it this way.

I found this to be the easiest way to translate stuff, though Im not sure if its the best or cleanest.

Comment: One disadvantage of using inline translation is you have to re-import the data when you are installing your new theme.

Answer (score 0):

If it can’t be translated via the integrated translator, you should do it using [theme]/locale.

But don’t touch the other places, if you want to update Magento without problems in the future.